# Not able to write into a file using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
from itertools import product

f = open('filename.txt', 'a')

def worker(i, j):
    print i,j
    f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(i,j))
    return

def main():
    a_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] #5 item
    b_list = ['6', '7', '8'] #3 item
    # Total 5*3=15 combinations

    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    results = [pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i, j)) for i, j in product(a_list, b_list)]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]

main()
f.close()
```

this is the code I'm trying to run and store result in a  txt file but I'm unable to findout why this isn't writing, although its printing in terminal. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this linux or windows? Does the content appear in the file after the script terminates?

Comment: its linux(ubuntu). I get blank file after completion of this program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `f.flush()` after the `f.write(...)` statement

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain me the issue because I've never face such situation.

Comment: @michael I believe the reason is that, because the file object isn't opened in your worker process, it doesn't automatically get flushed/closed when the worker exits. Because of this, your write never actually gets written to the file, it just gets written to a buffer local to the worker, which is then lost when the process exits.